# Python requests - get specific cookie value

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get the value of the **frontend_cid** cookie on a website however I'm running into some difficulties. The value of the cookie should look something like this: `fjwkkbQxJcTpLTP2`

Right now this is the code I have:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.get('website here')

frontend_cid_cookie = s.cookies['frontend_cid']
print(frontend_cid_cookie)
```

But that seems to be throwing me a NoneType when I try add it to another string... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi James, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please provide the whole stacktrace from when the errors occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote is right. 
Try to `print(s.cookies.get_dict())` and look the cookies you have. From there you can see what's wrong

Comment: I have done exactly that and it's just returning {}, but thats not possible since I know for a fact there are over a dozen cookies on the page...

Comment: Maybe there are, but the problem could that the page understand that the request comes from a script and doesn't load them. One thing: try changing the "s" from "session()" to "S", uppercase.

Comment: Yep, I got you. I simply added some headers to the request and now everything works fine. Cheers :)